# Updating XML nodes from an object list in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML file with this structure:

```
<inventory>
<product>
    <recordNumber>1</recordNumber>
    <name>Dustbin</name>
    <stock>190</stock>
    <price>33</price>
</product>
<product>
    <recordNumber>2</recordNumber>
    <name>Broom</name>
    <stock>200</stock>
    <price>76</price>
</product>

</inventory>
```

I have a program which takes in these values and creates a List of 'Item' objects called 'stockArray'. each item has an int-Id(from `recordNumber`) and an int-count(from `stock`).

The program updates the "stock" value accordingly and what I am looking to do is then update the XML file to have the new 'stock' value.

I am very new to C# and XML, so this is the path I have been going down:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);

var list = doc.Element("inventory").Elements("product");

foreach (var node in list)
{
    foreach (Item item in stockArray)
    {
        if (node.Element("recordNumber").Value == Convert.ToString(item.Id))
            node.SetElementValue("count", Convert.ToString(item.count));
    }
}
```

But so far this seems way off course. I can find a lot of information about adding new nodes to an XML but iterating through the `stockArray` item list and updating the XML seems to be a different process.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: Probably that it is very slow if the file is large.  YOu have to iterate over everything. Yuck.  I'd look into using linq

Comment: It does not seem to be modifying the XML document at all. When I reload the program the original stock number is there. Thanks

Comment: @Daviepark Have you called `doc.Save(myPathToTheXmlFile)` ?

Comment: @CédricBignon - sorry I forgot to put that in. Yes I have that.

Comment: When you debug the program, is `node.SetElementValue("count", Convert.ToString(item.count));` called?
And is `Convert.ToString(item.count) != node.Element("recordNumber").Value`?
These questions seem obvious but I don't see any functional issue in your program. Performance-wise, we'll improve it later ;)

Comment: you don't have `<count>` element, did you mean `stock` : `node.SetElementValue("stock", Convert.ToString(item.count));` ?

Comment: @har07 -- Wow... thanks for helping me with that, my brain just is not working today! So simple.
Just out of curiosity, what would be the better LINQ way to do this?

Comment: See my answer below, but you can grab the node without having to use a recursive for loop to find it.  One of the best things about c#!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML doesn't have `<count>` element. If you meant to update `<stock>` element value, the first parameter of `SetElementValue()` should be `"stock"` :

```
if (node.Element("recordNumber").Value == Convert.ToString(item.Id))
    node.SetElementValue("stock", Convert.ToString(item.count));
```

One possible way using LINQ join to create anonymous type that pair `<product>` element with the corresponding item from `stockArray` :

```
var list = from product in doc.Element("inventory").Elements("product")
           join item in stockArray on (int)product.Element("recordNumber") equals item.id
           select new {product = product, item = item};
foreach (var joinedProduct in list)
{
    joinedProduct.product.SetElementValue("stock", joinedProduct.item.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but you will want to do some error handling for null values.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
var list = doc.Element("inventory").Elements("product");

 foreach (var item in stockArray)
   {
   var node = list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Element("recordNumber").Value == item.ToString());
            node.Element("stock").Value = item.Count.ToString();
   }
```

Edit: fixing the code!

Comment: `p => (string)p.Element("recordNumber") == item.ToString()` will handle the case of an element being null without having to check if it's null or not (or if the element is missing).

Comment: That is rad! Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

You are editing the `count` element instead of `stock` element.

And to improve performance (here the complexity is O(n^2)). You can create a dictionary from the `stockArray`.

Creating the dictionary has a complexity of O(n).
And getting a value in the dictionary has a complexity of O(1).

So, the complexity of the program with the dictionary is O(n).

I would also suggest you to use the [explicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348319(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert the value of the `XElement` to `int`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(xml);

var list = doc.Element("inventory").Elements("product");
var stockDictionary = stockArray.ToDictionary(item => item.Id, item => item.Count);

foreach (var node in list)
{
    int newCount;
    if (if(stockDictionary.TryGetValue((int)node.Element("recordNumber"), out newCount)
        node.SetElementValue("stock", newCount);
}
```

Comment: Does the compiler automatically generate a recursive loop from LINQ Statements.  For example if he grabbed the node using:list.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Element("recordNumber").Value ....

Comment: Yes it does (in a way). This is why the complexity of using `list.FirstOrDefault(...)` is O(n). So with this, the complexity of the program is still O(n^2). There is a way to do it in pure LINQ without dictionaries and having a O(n) complexity for the program (using the `.Join(...)` method) but it unecessarily complexify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlSerializer to do this. Only thing is you have to write your xml structure as classes. see the code sample.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
        FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\files\data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);

        // Load the object saved above by using the Deserialize function
        Inventory LoadedObj = (Inventory)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);

        // Cleanup
        ReadFileStream.Close();

        foreach (var node in LoadedObj.Products)
        {
             // node.Stock = 0;
            //Do what ever changes to stock
        }

        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Inventory));
        //// Create a new file stream to write the serialized object to a file
        TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\files\data.xml");
        SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, TestObj);
        //// Cleanup
        WriteFileStream.Close();


    }
}


[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("inventory")]
public class Inventory
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("product")]
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

}

[System.SerializableAttribute()]

   public class Product
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("recordNumber")]
    public string RecordNumber { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("stock")]
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("price")]
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```